# Trying to swap content if user value is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Final code (working):

```
%%[var @offer12, @dateInput, @zeroData
set @dateInput = Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy")
set @zeroData = Offer12]%%


%%[IF not empty(Offer12) THEN
set @offer12 = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\",@dateInput,"\",@zeroData))

ELSE

Set @offer12 = ContentAreaByName("my contents\DefaultOffer")]%%

%%[endif]%%
%%=v(@offer12)=%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no dash in `ENDIF` and you've mixed quotes on the second `concat()`.  You don't need the second `concat()` anyway.

```
%%[ 
Var @offer12 
IF not empty(OFFER12) THEN
  set @offer12 = ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\resp\",  Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"),'\',OFFER12))
ELSE   
  set @offer12 = ContentAreaByName("my contents\DefaultOffer")  
ENDIF 
]%%
%%=v(@offer12)=%%
```

EDIT: here's how I would break it down to debug:

```
%%[ 
Var @path, @inputDate, @offer12

set @inputDate0 = [InputDate]
set @inputDate = Format(DateAdd(@inputDate0, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy")
set @offer12 = [OFFER12]

IF not empty(@offer12) THEN
  set @path = concat("my contents\resp\", @inputDate  ,'\',@offer12)

ELSE   
  set @path = "my contents\DefaultOffer"
ENDIF 
]%%
inputDate: %%=v(@inputDate0)=%%
<br>inputDate0: %%=v(@inputDate)=%%
<br>offer12: %%=v(@offer12)=%%
<br>path: %%=v(@path)=%%
%%[ /* output the ContentAreaByName(@path) here after you've verified @path value */ ]%%
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Adam, it looks like I'm still getting errors:

A scripting error has occurred.
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a ContentAreaByName function call.
Function Call: ContentAreaByName(concat("my contents\eStmt_Responsive\", Format(DateAdd(InputDate, "1","M"), "MMMM yyyy"),'\',OFFER12))
See inner exception for details.

Comment: Updated my answer with how I'd break it down to debug.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Was able to get it to work :D  Posted the final code incase anyone else runs into this issue

Comment: Awesome.  Please mark your question as answered.